# Error with i18n when i put a badge in appbar

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I a working with vuejs & vuetify, when i put a badge in my appbar i recive a warning from i18n:

vue-i18n.esm.js?a925:33 [vue-i18n] Value of key '$vuetify.badge' is not a string!

vue-i18n.esm.js?a925:33 [vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath '$vuetify.badge'. Use the value of keypath as default.

```
<template>
    <v-btn class="ml-2" min-width="0" text v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
      <v-badge color="red" overlap bordered>
        <template v-slot:badge>
          <span>5</span>
        </template>

        <v-icon>mdi-bell</v-icon>
      </v-badge>
    </v-btn>
</template>
```

It has happened to someone or someone knows how to deal with it

Thanks:

Jose Rodriguez

Answer (score 0):

One hacky solution is to set a dummy value for '$vuetify.badge' and this removes the warning.
Badge works correctly with or without this value.

Answer (score 0):

`$vuetify.badge` is the default value for the badge "label" property. So as @Govind said, you can set the '$vuetify.badge' value.

You can also directly add the `label="your label"` attribute to your badge.

As stated [here](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/201), you can also disable globally those warnings.